# How to pass a reference of an object to a function for reuse

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to adhere to DRY principles in my first Python app (I'm an experienced .NET developer). I've been able to move most of my repeated code into reusable functions.

For example, here is how I am creating lines (bounding boxes) for a matplotlib plot:

```
def generate_bounding_box_polygon(comma_delimited_rect: str):
    box_coordinates = comma_delimited_rect.strip().split(',')
    x = int(box_coordinates[0].strip())
    y = int(box_coordinates[1].strip())
    width = int(box_coordinates[2].strip())
    height = int(box_coordinates[3].strip())
    bottom_left = [x, y]
    bottom_right = [x + width, y]
    top_left = [x, y + height]
    top_right = [x + width, y + height]
    points = [bottom_left, top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left]
    polygon = plt.Polygon(points, fill=None, edgecolor='xkcd:rusty red', closed=False)
    return polygon
```

I reuse this when creating bounding boxes for my plot. This nested for loop is in several functions, so having the `generate_bounding_boxes` function is nice and neat

```
for region in result["regions"]:
    region_box = generate_bounding_box_polygon(region["boundingBox"])
    plt.gca().add_line(region_box)

    for line in region["lines"]:
        line_box = generate_bounding_box_polygon(line["boundingBox"])
        plt.gca().add_line(line_box)

        for word in line["words"]:
            detected_text += word
            word_box = generate_bounding_box_polygon(word["boundingBox"])
            plt.gca().add_line(word_box)

            # RELEVANT  this is the code I want to move into a function
            box_coordinates = word["boundingBox"].strip().split(',')
            x = int(box_coordinates[0].strip())
            y = int(box_coordinates[1].strip())
            plt.gca().text(x, y-10, word["text"], fontsize=8)
```

However, notice that last code comment, I want to also move the `text` method into  a function but I would need a reference to `plt.gca()`

How can I pass that to a function as a parameter? I tried the following (see the 2nd parameter, `plot`) like I would do in C# but it's not working and probably bad practice in python:

```
def render_text(comma_delimited_rect: str, plot: matplotlib.pyplot):
    box_coordinates = comma_delimited_rect.strip().split(',')
    x = int(box_coordinates[0].strip())
    y = int(box_coordinates[1].strip())
    plt.gca().text(x, y-10, word["text"], fontsize=8)
```

Note: `plt` is defined as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: You can see the entire code file here https://github.com/LanceMcCarthy/MachineLearningFun/blob/master/PythonProjects/CognitiveServicesPlayground/CognitiveServicesPlayground/cognitive_services_playground.py

Comment: Please don't give an off-site reference to "the entire code".  We need the [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `plt.gca()` inside of your function anyways, there is no need for the additional argument.

```
def render_text(comma_delimited_rect):
    box_coordinates = comma_delimited_rect.strip().split(',')
    x = int(box_coordinates[0].strip())
    y = int(box_coordinates[1].strip())
    plt.gca().text(x, y-10, word["text"], fontsize=8)
```

If instead you want to pass the axes to plot to, you would supply this to the function

```
def render_text(comma_delimited_rect, word, axes):
    box_coordinates = comma_delimited_rect.strip().split(',')
    x = int(box_coordinates[0].strip())
    y = int(box_coordinates[1].strip())
    axes.text(x, y-10, word, fontsize=8)
```

calling it with e.g.

```
render_text( word["boundingBox"],  word["text"], plt.gca())
```

Comment: I suspected this was possible as the `plt` object looks like a global static (or whatever a singleton is in python), but wasn't sure about expecting this to be valid across multiple method calls (there are other functions that call render_text)

Comment: All of this assumes that you have `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in you code. Then `plt` is a **module**. But sure, this is in the global namespace.

Comment: Correct, that's exact how it's declared. I should have added this to my question to clarify what `plt` was. So, the bottom line is that because it's a module, I'm not actually passing an object reference as all, just pointing to the module's instance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the actual code you're using, but I think what you want is something like this:

```
def render_text(comma_delimited_rect: str, plot: matplotlib.pyplot):
    box_coordinates = comma_delimited_rect.strip().split(',')
    x = int(box_coordinates[0].strip())
    y = int(box_coordinates[1].strip())
    plot().text(x, y-10, word["text"], fontsize=8)
```

... and called with ...

```
render_text(word["boundingBox"], plt.gca)
```

Note how you pass the plotting function *as a function*, rather than as the result of a call -- no parentheses.

Comment: This didn't work (because the parameter's type definition failed), but a small tweak was successful. Changed parameter type to `plot: plt`, which was used with `plot.gca().text(...)` and called using `render_word(comma_delimited_rect=word["boundingBox"], plot=plt)`. Thanks!

Comment: See final source here https://github.com/LanceMcCarthy/MachineLearningFun/blob/20565e5a6371913196d98c7eed67012c8dfdb61a/PythonProjects/CognitiveServicesPlayground/CognitiveServicesPlayground/cognitive_services_playground.py#L26-L31